# Where to put "Q.longStackSupport = true"?

Tags: javascript, promise, q

From the [documentation of Q](https://www.npmjs.org/package/q) (the Javascript promise library):

```
Q.longStackSupport = true;
```

> This feature does come with somewhat-serious performance and memory overhead, however. If you're working with lots of promises, or trying to scale a server to many users, you should probably keep it off. But in development, go for it!

I find myself always writing code like this:

```
var Q = require('q');
Q.longStackSupport = true;
```

However, if I decided to turn off `longStackSupport`, I would have to touch a lot of files in my code.

So, I wonder if there is a more elegant solution:

- Is there a recommended pattern when including Q?
- Is it sufficient to call `Q.longStackSupport` only once?

Comment: Honestly I'd consider Bluebird if I were you, it has long stack traces that are actually meaningful.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Thanks a lot, very interesting. I was a bit skeptial first, as there are so many implementations to choose from. After having read more about it, I'll definitely give it a try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it is sufficient to only call it once in one place.

In init.js, or whatever your root file is, I would put

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV === "development") {
    Q.longStackSupport = true;
}
```

Then this will automatically enable it if you have the NODE_ENV environment variable set to development.

```
$ export NODE_ENV=development
$ node init.js
```